# Defining 2 MX-Records for one domain using ddclient

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns

I have a domain from Strato and I am using dyndns (ddclient runs on my server). I just started using protonmail and I now want to use my domain with proton. This requires me to set 2 different MX-Records (no, they are not getting used at once, they have different priorities and one is just the backup for the other).

My current configuration:

```
daemon=600
syslog=yes
pid=/var/run/ddclient.pid
ssl=yes

use=web
protocol=dyndns2
server=dyndns.strato.com/nic/update
login=...
password='...'
mx=mailsec.protonmail.ch
mxprio=10
bgfxc4.de
```

This works fine for one MX-record (`mailsec.protonmail.ch`) but I need to add `mail.protonmail.ch` with priority 20.

I also tried asking ChatGPT, and they suggested this:

```
mx=mailsec.protonmail.ch,10
mx=mail.protonmail.ch,20
```

which is completle nonsense and does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'dyndns2' protocol only supports one 'mx' field. The source code of ddclient hints that you might be able to specify a comma-separated list, but whether it actually works will most likely depend on the provider:

```
mx=mailsec.protonmail.ch,mail.protonmail.ch
```

There is no way to specify exact priorities (presumably the DDNS server will assign some priorities in increasing order, the exact numbers shouldn't matter). In fact, even your `mxprio=` is nonfunctional; there is no such parameter anywhere within the ddclient source code and it is not passed to the DDNS server.

In practice, a single MX should be sufficient. Senders will typically retry delivery for up to 3-7 days, and it is unlikely that ProtonMail would be down for so long; besides, each of those two domain names already points to three different IP addresses at once, so even a single MX will already have a built-in backup of sorts.

(But also, the ones for the 'backup' domain are all in the exact same /24's as the 'primary', anyway – so if all three 'primary' hosts go down at once, my bet is that all three 'backup' hosts will just go down together with them.)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Regarding the `mxprio` it seems like I misread the documentation, the argument is called `mxpri` (which I used, I just made a typo in the question), but is only available on a different protocol, not dyndns2.


I already tried seperating the different Domains within one mx-field, but ddclient does not accept that (`FAILED:   updating mail.protonmail.ch: nohost: The hostname specified does not exist in the database`).

Comment: There is no `mxpri` in the ddclient codebase, either. The only MX-related field (both configuration and protocol) that it supports is just `mx`, and it is single-valued. If your DDNS **server** rejects commas in the 'mx' field, then the conclusion is that it just doesn't support that.

Comment: Well ok, that is weird. Right here it is specified: https://ddclient.net/protocols.html#dnspark-protocol.

And well, the server does not reject it, it just thinks that the domain after the comma is the domain for the dyndns because a comma seems to be the same as a new line. And that was my whole problem: finding a way to specify it in the ddclient config

Comment: @bgfxc4: That's only for `protocol=dnspark`, which 1) you aren't using (you are using "dyndns2"), and 2) was removed from ddclient in 2020 ("Removing dnspark as the service doesn't exist anymore").

Comment: Yep, saw that too. As I said, I misread the docs